# How to loop a column data with comma separator using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
id | value

1  | 0, 1

2  | 0,1,2
```

**`table_1`**

1. I have a table known as **table_1** which have **id** and **value** column.
2. I would like to loop through the **value** column for each data which is seperated with comma.
3. Then, I would like to insert the every data into a new table.

As below:

```
id | value

1  | 0

1  | 1

2  | 0

2  | 1

2  | 2
```

**`table_2`**

1. This means that in table_2, it will have two rows of when user_id=1.
2. Example: user_id = 1, value = 0
           user_id =1, value = 1

How to achieve this? Your response is very much appreciated.

Comment: I would say, write a script that does this :)

Comment: Write a procedure to get its working.

Comment: in which script you are using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you want the opposite of GROUP_CONCAT() function.

I found this, that might work for you : http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=92

Hope that helps.